# Meaning of the phrase "relief efforts"

Tags: meaning-in-context, interpretation

I am trying to understand the following question:

> She'll be coordinating the **relief effort.**

Consulting dictionaries, I found the following definitions:

> **Relief** - any aid given in times of need, danger, or disaster, as supplies sent into a flooded area.

> **Effort** - an attempt to do something.

Although I understand the meaning of the separate words, I still need help to understand the precise meaning of the two words used together here in a phrase. Can you help me understand the intended meaning?

Comment: Relief efforts are attempts to give aid.

Comment: She will be coordinating the activities of all the people who are working to provide relief.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an alternative definition of “effort” that applies here. From [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/effort):

> An effort is a particular series of activities that is organized by a group of people in order to achieve something.

So a “relief effort” is an organised series of activities by a group of people to provide relief(aid).